# RMI server finds scala.Option when run from IDE but cannot do it when run from sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, rmi

I am trying to spawn one JVM process from another and make them communicate via RMI. I managed to make it work from IDE, but for some reason when I try to run the code from `sbt` it fails with:

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

My problem is figuring out what changes between running it from IDE and SBT.

#### Code

First I am trying to create registry with random port number to avoid failure due to used port:

```
@tailrec
def getRegister(attemptsLeft: Integer = 10): (Registry, Integer) = {
  val possiblePorts = (1024 to 65536)
  val randomPort    = possiblePorts(scala.util.Random.nextInt(possiblePorts.size))

  Try (LocateRegistry createRegistry randomPort) match {
    case Success(registry) => (registry, randomPort)
    case Failure(ex)       => if (attemptsLeft <= 0) throw ex
                              else getRegister(attemptsLeft - 1)
  }
}
```

I used `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` because it should solve problems with starting and ending RMI process and passing current classpath into it.

When I start child process I copy class path of the parent process - main class is contained within the same project so I can simply copy JVM arguments used to run parent process to make sure that it will have access to the same libraries.

Then child process used following code:

```
Try {
  val server   = ... // class which will do the job
  val stub     = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0).asInstanceOf[Server]
  val registry = LocateRegistry getRegistry remotePort

  registry.bind(serverName, stub) // throws in SBT, succeeds in IDE
} match {
  case Success(_)  => logger debug "Remote ready"
  case Failure(ex) => logger error("Remote failed", ex)
                      System exit -1
}
```

What did I missed? Using `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` should copy the class path of the parent process (which uses `Option` in several places already, it has to have access to the class), child process has access this class as well (I checked to be sure). Yet for some reason when I run the code from under the `sbt` `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` fails to pass `scala.Option` location to the classpath.

Comment: Process elevation - I want Scala to do some heavy lifting requiring admin privileges and I found one elevated child process (and one password pop-up) to be better than several of them (and root password pop-up spam). I also found RMI to be much cleaner, than manual stream parsing and multiplexing for 2 JVM processes that are aleady sharing clas spath and user directory. As for why elevating process in Scala, I think that creating custom DSL for very specific backup needs might be much funner than maintenance of big-ass repetitive bash scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work setting up `java.rmi.server.codebase` System property.

I am not sure what actually broke and I would be glad if someone actually explained it. My wild guess it that when I run `LocateRegistry getRegistry remotePort` it makes use of `"java.class.path"` which is kind of unreliable.

When I start application from IDE it passes all deps directly to JVM - all JARs used appear in `java.class.path`. On the other hand when I start it from SBT all I get is `/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar`.

I didn't noticed the issue because I don't rely on this property while populating class path argument for child JVM. Instead I used something like:

```
lazy val javaHome = System getProperty "java.home"

lazy val classPath = System getProperty "java.class.path"

private lazy val jarClassPathPattern  = "jar:(file:)?([^!]+)!.+".r
private lazy val fileClassPathPattern = "file:(.+).class".r

def classPathFor[T](clazz: Class[T]): List[String] = {
  val pathToClass = getPathToClassFor(clazz)

  val propClassPath   = classPath split File.pathSeparator toSet

  val loaderClassPath = clazz.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(_.getFile).toSet

  val jarClassPath    = jarClassPathPattern.findFirstMatchIn(pathToClass) map { matcher =>
    val jarDir = Paths get (matcher group 2) getParent()
    s"${jarDir}/*"
  } toSet

  val fileClassPath   = fileClassPathPattern.findFirstMatchIn(pathToClass) map { matcher =>
    val suffix   = "/" + clazz.getName
    val fullPath = matcher group 1
    fullPath substring (0, fullPath.length - suffix.length)
  } toSet

  (propClassPath ++ loaderClassPath ++ jarClassPath ++ fileClassPath ++ Set(".")).toList
}

def getPathToClassFor[T](clazz: Class[T]) = {
  val url = clazz getResource s"${clazz.getSimpleName}.class"
  Try (URLDecoder decode (url.toString, "UTF-8")) match {
    case Success(classFilePath) => classFilePath
    case Failure(_)             => throw new IllegalStateException("")
  }
}
```

After reusing those additional JARs in `java.rmi.server.codebase` everything started to work reliably:

```
def configureRMIFor[T](clazz: Class[T]): Unit = {
  val classPath = classPathFor(clazz)
  val codebase  = if (classPath isEmpty) ""
                  else classPath map (new File(_).getAbsoluteFile.toURI.toURL.toString) reduce (_ + " " + _)

  logger trace s"Set java.rmi.server.codebase to: $codebase"
  System setProperty ("java.rmi.server.codebase", codebase)
}
```

Still, I it would be nice if someone more knowledgeable would come and explain it what exactly made the difference.